# Range of application

Tags: single-word-requests

"Effectiveness" is how good the results are of a method, "Efficiency" is how much result I can get, in comparison to the resources I need to spend (e.g. computing power for computational algorithms). I am searching for a word (ideally from of the same etymological origin, starting with "E"), that denotes the notion of "how far the range of application" is, in other words, in how many situations I can use this method.

**Example sentence:**

"The algorithm is computationally expensive, so we need a powerful computer, but it is very effective, yielding great results and that (what is more) in a very a wide range of situations. Its *WORD* is its most impressive feature: We are will not have to implement any other algorithm."

Comment: It's not clear where in your example sentence you want a new word.

Comment: FLEXIBILITY   doesn't start with "e" but phonetically close

Comment: Is your example sentence the only one you’re interested in, so in fact it’s not an example but the only sentence in question, or are there other examples, please?

I suspect you’re on a hiding to nothing and still, if you could rid that rather extended example of extraneous clutter, more would become clearer.

There’s nothing wrong with *… so we need a powerful computer* but neither is it useful. Such phrases make the meaning harder, not easier to follow.

*efficiency* seems right for the example, if not for you. Uncertain’s *flexibility* likewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **versatile**
>   [vur-suh-tl or, esp. British, -tahyl]
>   adjective/
>
> 1. capable of or adapted for turning easily from one to another of various tasks, fields of endeavor, etc.
> 2. having or capable of many uses
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/versatility)

*The algorithm is computationally expensive, so we need a powerful computer, but it is very effective, yielding great results in a very wide range of situations. Its* **versatility** *is its most impressive feature....*

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of fitting words similar to "Effectiveness" and "Efficiency".

However, the term in Computer Science generally used to describe such multi-purpose algorithms is **genericity** (the property of being **generic**).

> The algorithm is computationally expensive, so we need a powerful computer, but it is very effective, yielding great results and that (what is more) in a very a wide range of situations. Its genericity is its most impressive feature: We are will not have to implement any other algorithm."

Another word that can fit here is **applicability**.